# JClouds-Chef BootstrapConfig Builder MissingMethodException

Tags: java, groovy, chef-infra, jclouds

**Please note**: although this question involve the [JClouds-Chef](http://jclouds.apache.org/guides/chef/) library and Groovy here, I think this is a Java API question at heart.

On JClouds-Chef 1.7.3 here:

```
List<String> runlist = new RunListBuilder().addRole("typicalapp").build();

ArrayList<String> runList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String item : runlist) {
    runList2.add(item);
}

System.out.println("runList2 is of type: " + runList2.getClass().getName());

BootstrapConfig bootstrapConfig = BootstrapConfig.builder().runlist(runList2).build();
```

Produces the following output/exception:

```
runList2 is of type: java.util.ArrayList
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jclouds.chef.domain.BootstrapConfig$Builder.runlist() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[role[typicalapp]]]
Possible solutions: runList(java.lang.Iterable), build(), split(groovy.lang.Closure)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at net.myuser.chef.test.ChefPlugin.provision(ChefPlugin.groovy:71)
    at net.myuser.chef.test.ChefPlugin$provision.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at net.myuser.chef.test.ChefPlugin.main(ChefPlugin.groovy:27)
```

I'm pretty sure the code for this version of [`BootstrapConfig#Builder` is here](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-chef/blob/1.7.x/core/src/main/java/org/jclouds/chef/domain/BootstrapConfig.java). As far as I can tell, `ArrayList` extends `Iterable`, so I can't see what's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `runlist` instead of `runList`

Comment: Thanks @Vartlok (+1) - "*curse you, Groovy!*"